# Multiple backgrounds with different background-size

Tags: css

I am trying to create a page background with an overlay using [css3](/questions/tagged/css3)'s multiple background support;

```
html, body {
  background: url('https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas/raw/master/overlays/01.png') repeat,
              url('http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7260/7502004958_595bf03fbf_z.jpg') top left no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}​
```

I want the photo background image to "cover" the page and the overlay to be small (3*3px) repeating over the hole page.

The above example gives me http://jsfiddle.net/tpmD4/ (also the overlay covering the page).

How can I fix that?

When I try to specify the [background-size](/questions/tagged/background-size) for both of the images (`background-size: 3px 3px, cover;`); then the image background doesn't cover, but the overlay works.

Comment: Not sure if what you're trying to do is possible, but it seems like it should be as it would make sense to be able to specify the background-size property for each image.

Only think I can think to do is place a div with width & height 100% and place your second background image on that div.

Comment: This page suggest that it should work: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/ ----  #examplen {
width: 580px;
height: 200px;
background-image: url(img/sheep.png), url(img/sheep.png), url(img/betweengrassandsky.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 20px 100px, 400px 50px, center bottom;
background-color: #EEE;
background-size: 70px, auto, cover;
}

Comment: Okey I also think it should be posible, I have thought about your idea but I am just trying to avoid the second div if it is posible.. thx!

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Here you go:

```
html, body {
    background-image: url(01.png), url(z.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: 3px 3px, cover;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tpmD4/6/

Comment: Of course, you don't want to have a single small image cover the whole background, you want to repeat it at the proper size!  Thanks so much for this!

Comment: It might be maybe something broken in the latest version of chrome, but the background-size and position properties aren't doing anything for me. Comma separated backgrounds work just fine though.

Comment: @Gopherkhan I know this is a late reply but just in case. I had a similar issue with background-size, the issue was with using inherit or initial when doing multiple sizes. Using auto instead fixed the issue for me. A bit more of an [explanation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Syntax)